# No "Add image server connection" button in Customize toolbar starting from ArcMap 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-image-server

Every ArcMap version till 10.5 had this button and I was using it to add orthophoto as a layer. I don't really know much about servers and I wonder if it's possible to add same layers using same server address (only numbers like: 00.00.0.00) I used before in new ArcMap as I don't have that button anymore

Comment: There's a difference between adding an "orthophoto" and adding an "orthophoto web service layet". Try using the "Add GIS Server" button (it supports more than just image services). You'll probably need to give more than an IP address.

Comment: The source of the layer I add from Image server is "ImageService://ip/". I don't know how "translate" it so I can add it from ArcGIS Server

Comment: Look at the documentation for examples. You need to know if it's an HTTP or HTTPS service, the IP address/FQDN, and the service path (which might be just `arcgis` but could literally be anything.

Comment: Thanks but as I said I don't know much about servers and was hoping for easy step-by-step  guide/solution of the problem if possible. Why do they even remove that button at the first place? :(

Comment: They *didn't* remove the button, they renamed it to reflect the changes in web-based mapping that had occurred. If you're not willing to try to solve your own problem you may find it difficult to find others willing to do so either.

Comment: So you say adding it from "Add ArcGIS Server" is the only option?